# How to get only real contact photos?

Tags: google-people-api

How to get only real contact photos from the Google People API? In general, there are photos for all contact, but many only with a colorized character. Real photos are for me the ones from user profiles or which I added manually in Google contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use photos with `person.photos.default` == false. See https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#photo